# Шляпа Third Time's A Charm. Неясно за что получить

Tags: дефект, предложение, локализация, новогодние-шляпы

Описание знака Third Time's A Charm

> достигните лимита репутации за день три раза

мне ни о чём не говорит. Что это за лимит репутации?

---

### UPDATE

Даже если бы я знал про  лимит репутации в 200 очков, то всё равно бы не так понял за что дают эту шляпу.

Текущее описание вводит в заблуждение, потому что возникает ощущение, что "достигнуть за день три раза", это имеется ввиду один и тот же день (то есть над 600+ в один день).

Предлагаю заменить описание на "Надо 3 дня набирать по 200+ баллов за каждый." или что-то подобное.

---

Для несекретных шляп есть также [полезный ответ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/288272/346987) на главной мете.

Comment: 200 баллов в день

Comment: [_В день можно заработать до 200 баллов репутации любым сочетанием приведенных ниже действий_](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation)

Comment: @Grundy на самом деле это вранье. у некоторых участников хорошо видно, что в день и без всяких конкурсов прилетает и до 300 и выше репы....... либо я чё не понимаю

Comment: @АлексейШиманский: Можно заработать не больше 200 баллов в день плюсами за ответы, остальные не засчитываются. Плюс дополнительные баллы за принятые ответы и выигранные конкурсы.

Comment: Плюс описание не вполне корректно, не обязательно именно достичь лимита, можно 200 баллов с конкурсами и принятыми ответами, без лимита собственно, и шляпа говорят зачтется

Comment: @VladD, за вопросы и ответы. А не только за ответы.

Comment: @Qwertiy: Угу, точно!

Comment: Хорошо, то есть надо просто заработать 600 репутации за один день и всё?

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov, нет, 3 дня по 200+.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Надо 3 дня набирать по 200+ баллов за каждый.

Comment: Предлагаю изменить описание на это

Comment: А 3 дня подряд или необязательно?

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov можно не подряд.

Comment: @NickVolynkin была тема про `подряд` очень популярна несколько лет назад ... но это надо обсуждать в специализированном [чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47216/ru-so) :)

Comment: А `200+` это `[200...)` или `[201...)`? Лучше уж написать `не менее 200`.

Comment: @alexolut, вроде все программисты понимают такую запись?

Comment: Про `не менее` поймёт ещё больше :)